# Number of ways to rearrange a line of $n$ marbles

Tags: probability, combinatorics

My friend challenged me to solve the following problem, and after having thought about it for a long time and not being able to find the answer, I decided to give up. His explanation which followed wasn't very clear, and I've already forgotten the answer, but I'm still curious. Here is the problem:

You have green, blue and red marbles at your disposal, and you would like to arrange them in a single line of $n$ marbles long. Green marbles can never be put next to each other. Others can. In how many different ways can you rearrange a line of 10 marbles long?

I would also like to know the general formula for the possibilities of a line of $n$ marbles long. An explanation would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line of length $n$ can begin R or B followed by a line of length $n-1$, or GR or GB followed by a line of length $n-2$.  If $S(k)$ counts the number of lines of length $k$, we have

$$S(n)=2S(n-1)+2S(n-2)$$

with $S(1)=3$ and $S(2)=8$.  Can you take it from there?